# How to access child nodes of a React components to add a wrapper components to them

Tags: reactjs

I have a layout component `GridLayout` that receives a react component `WigdetsList`. That component is a functional component that returns a list of components.

I would like to be able to add a wrapper component to each of this component's child nodes in the list.

If I use `{WigdetsList()}` instead `<WigdetsList />` it would work since it becomes a function that returns an array. But I would like to be able to use a react component there if possible. Therefore it becomes a single child.

I do not wish to put `<Col key={i} xs={12} lg={4}>` in the `WidgetsList` since I want to separate concerns. Layout components to do layouting and functionality components that are not coupled to specific layouts components.

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-brown-u9yr1

App:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <GridLayout>
      <WigdetsList />
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

WidgetsList:

```
function WidgetsList() {
  return widgets.map(widget => (
    <StyledWidget key={widget.id}>widget {widget.id}</StyledWidget>
  ));
}
```

GridLayout:

```
function GridLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        {React.Children.map(children, (child, i) => (
          <Col key={i} xs={12} lg={4}>
            {child}
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: You could use [`React.Children.forEach`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenforeach)

Comment: @GiddharthSupta No, replacing React.Children.map by React.Children.forEach will not work. You still have only one children. I want to access the child nodes of that react component.

Answer (score -1):

`WidgetsList` does not need to be a React component. It returns a list of React components, without any render logic. So, it should be a function or inline within `App` itself:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <GridLayout>
      {widgets.map(widget => (
        <StyledWidget key={widget.id}>widget {widget.id}</StyledWidget>
      ))}
    </GridLayout>
  );
}
```

If `WidgetsList` was rendered as a table--for example--then the `Col`'s should be created inside of it, since the component now cares about its own layout.

Comment: 3rd paragraph of my question says exactly that. I know this works, I want to know if I can achieve this using a component. Thanks

Comment: In your case, it does not make sense to use a React component (even if you can) because `WidgetsList` does not render anything. It is effectively an array.

Comment: Its a functional component that returns an array. It could return a fragment also, a div or whatver. The question remains.